# Best way to load a files (pdf, doc, img) through php - retaining filename/extension etc

Tags: php, file, file-handling

I'm doing a security check with PHP before loading a file, the file could be a jpg, pdf doc or similar.

1. Is there any library which would automate the different headers etc I need to do to output the file, without me having to check the file extension?
2. For pdfs and docs especially, since the user may download, It's not ideal to have the url being view_file.php?blah=blah. I guess the only alternative is to force a download and specify the filename?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP has [pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) to get a file paths extension, or [Fileinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/book.fileinfo.php) to get the mime-type.

As for obsecuring the URL, you could create a database with references to the file names, that way your url could look like `view_file.php?file_id=123`, noone will know its actually `important.doc`.